# OpenCv: FilterEngine() explanation / Create custom nonlinear filter

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, filtering

I would like to create my own **nonlinear** filter in OpenCV using C++, and if I see it correctly, I can use the FilterEngine class to do so. Unfortunately, I'm not really able to follow the documentation of this class. (Link: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filterengine).

Could someone be so kind to explain the class to me in a little bit more detail?

I'm grateful for every input and every example you can provide me with :-)

.

**My specific needs:**

1) I would like learn how to create my own nonlinear filters in general.

2) I would like to apply a rank-transform filter to my images:

Meaning: I have a kernel/region and I would like to flag every pixel inside that region with a one if the intensity-value of that (neighbourhood-) pixel is lower than the intensity of the center-pixel. Next, I want to use a simple convolution to save the sum of the transformed region, and store the value at the center-pixel. Let's look at a simple example:

```
100 120 200    rank-trans.    1 0 0     convolution
110 120 220        -->        1 0 0         -->        2
180 200 200                   0 0 0
```

P.S:  I know that I can archive the result of 2) by combining 255 threshold-operations with 255 box-filter operations, and then looping over every pixel and selecting the correct value. However, that seems quite inefficient to me ...

.

**Code-Snipped [Edit]:**

As I still struggle to understand the FilterEngine(), I started to write my own function for the above-descripted usecase. I would also be happy if you could comment on it to improve its efficiency, as it is quite slow at the moment. (~2sec. for a 1080x1920 image on one CPU-core).

```
void rankTransform(Mat& out, Mat in, int kernal_size, int borderType) {

// Issue warning if neccessary:
if (kernal_size >= 17) {
    std::cout << "Warning, need to change Mat-type. Unsigned short only supports kernels up-to the size of 15x15" << std::endl << std::endl;
};


// First: Get borders around the image:
int border_size = (kernal_size - 1) / 2;

Mat in_incl_border = Mat(1080 + 2 * border_size, 1920 + 2 * border_size, in.depth());
copyMakeBorder(in, in_incl_border, border_size, border_size, border_size, border_size, borderType);


// Second: Loop through the image, conduct a rank transform and 
// then sum over the kernel-size:

int start_pixel = 0 + (border_size + 1);
int end_pixel_width = 1920 + border_size;
int end_pixel_height = 1080 + border_size;

int i, j;
int x_1, x_2, y_1;

for (i = start_pixel; i < end_pixel_height; ++i) {
    x_1 = i - border_size;
    x_2 = i + border_size + 1;

    for (j = start_pixel; j < end_pixel_width; ++j) {

        y_1 = j - border_size;

        out.at<unsigned short>(x_1-1, y_1-1) = static_cast<unsigned short>( (sum( in_incl_border(Range(x_1, x_2), Range(y_1, j + border_size + 1)) < in_incl_border.at<unsigned short>(i, j) )[0])/255 );
    };
};
```